# HiddenField em aspx para cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, aspx

Eu tenho uma duvida acerca do hiddenfield em aspx utilizamos o seguinte comando:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

E para cshtml é possivel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Razor você pode utilizar o `@Html.HiddenFor()` que será muito útil se você estiver utilizando uma `Model`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Propriedade)
```

Caso contrário, como no exemplo apresentado na pergunta... não faz muito sentido criar esse componente no lado do servidor se ele for representar um objeto de modelo, mas pode ser feito, também:

```
@Html.Hidden("HiddenField1","valorQuandoSelecionado")
```

Nesse caso seria melhor escrever o html puro mesmo...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="HiddenField1" value="valorQuandoSelecionado" />
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado! @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Propriedade)